# Python IDLE seems to be unable to import Pyperclip in python 36?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compiler-errors, python-import, pyperclip

I am trying to  import the thing in python that will enable me to copy and past things. It seems to have a problem. I later searched my entire C drive for pyperclip and it seems to be not have it at all. How can I go about fixing this? Or am I not looking in the right area? Here is the error:

> import pyperclip
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> import pyperclip
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'

BTW I'm on windows 10

Answer (score 0):

You seems a new learner for Python. You can try to install that package via `pip` command. For other problem like how to use pip or which user to run pip, just go to search and solve it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

So yes you're right. You need to open up cmd prompt. use the **cd** to change the directory to the one inside Python36\Scripts. Then run the  command 
    **pip install pyperclip**